# How to specify a range of columns instead of entering one by one in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data table in CSV format:

```
    Dilution    Lotus1  Lotus2  Lotus3  Lotus5  Lotus6a Lotus6c Lotus7  Lotus8
0   1.301030    0.7769  0.1884  0.3076  0.3066  1.5722  2.1263  0.3414  1.3695
1   1.778151    0.3767  0.2567  0.1872  0.1902  1.1285  1.9726  0.2267  0.7549
2   2.301030    0.2267  0.2049  0.1454  0.1483  0.6637  1.7816  0.1720  0.4223
3   2.778151    0.1519  0.1507  0.1194  0.1174  0.3244  1.4958  0.1452  0.2062
4   3.301030    0.1234  0.1256  0.1270  0.1440  0.2273  1.3553  0.1383  0.1705
5   3.778151    0.1151  0.1190  0.1166  0.1143  0.1402  0.7333  0.1218  0.1295
6   4.301030    0.1213  0.1219  0.1201  0.1209  0.1335  0.4217  0.1241  0.1279
7   4.778151    0.1145  0.1181  0.1144  0.1196  0.1205  0.2609  0.1259  0.1219
```

and I have calculated the area under the curve (AUC) for each of the 8 Lotus samples, using the `trapz(x,y)` function:

```
from numpy import trapz

x = (elisa.Lotus1, elisa.Lotus2, elisa.Lotus3, elisa.Lotus5, elisa.Lotus6a, elisa.Lotus6c, elisa.Lotus7, elisa.Lotus8)
y = (elisa.Dilution)

AUC = trapz(x,y)

[0.77020294 0.56251883 0.50852258 0.51922454 1.71261157 4.44964193
 0.57552938 1.26143932]
```

Now, since I’m a python beginner, what I did here was manually entering the name of all the columns for the x axis, so my question is: What is the syntax to tell python to apply the same function in bulk to a range of columns, like columns 2-9, or Lotus1-Lotus8? I also have the same problem when plotting, since I used this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

x = ('elisa.Lotus1', 'elisa.Lotus2', 'elisa.Lotus3', 'elisa.Lotus5', 'elisa.Lotus6a', 'elisa.Lotus6c', 'elisa.Lotus7', 'elisa.Lotus8')
y = (0.77020294, 0.56251883, 0.50852258, 0.51922454, 1.71261157, 4.44964193, 0.57552938, 1.26143932)
```

I have scoured the web but I haven’t find resources to help me specifically with this issue, and I have hundreds of columns to process, so this piece of code would be really handy to have!

Anybody who knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try add the `axis = 0`

```
np.trapz(elisa.loc[:,'Lotus1':],elisa.Dilution,axis=0)
array([0.77020283, 0.56251879, 0.50852253, 0.51922449, 1.71261136,
       4.44964163, 0.57552932, 1.26143913])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried that, but it says that "np" is not defined. If I remove "np", then "elisa" is not defined

Answer (score 1):

There many ways of doing it, but it requires working with a list.

First method: using `df.columns`. This will return a list with all the column names you can slice or work with as you would regularly do with a list.

Second method: using `list(df)`. Similarly as before, this will return a list with all the names of the columns in the dataframe.

Third method: List comprehension: [x for x in df] return a list with all the names of the columns in df, in exchange, this is more flexible and allows filtering. For example in your case if you want to keep the columns that start with Lotus you can do:

```
[x for x in df if x.startswith('Lotus')]
```

Finally, given what you seem to be trying, which is to split the dataset into the columns that contain `Lotus` and the target column `Dilution` you can use pandas `.drop()` function:

```
X = elisa.drop(columns='Dilution') #Returns the dataframe without the specific column
y = elisa['Dilution'] #Returns a series
```

With the three first cases, you can simply pass the list to the dataframe, to filter the columns, or use `loc`.

For example:

```
lotus_columns = [x for x in df if x.startswith('Lotus')]
lotus_df = df[lotus_columns]
```

Another example using `df.columns` + slicing:

```
X = df[df.columns[1:]] #df.columns[1:] returns all columns except the first one
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your thorough answer! I will try all those options.